# rhev and number of cpus

Tags: central-processing-unit, rhev, ovirt

I use RHEV-M to manage a cluster which has several RHEV hypervisor nodes. Currently, each node has 2 CPU sockets.

My question is can I add to the RHEV cluster another node which has 4 sockets, and how will scheduling behave when I do that.

All CPUs are AMD and exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is no problem to mix such hosts. Scheduling should take this into account and load them according to their resources.

Comment: Is there documentation that shows this? Or is it from your experience?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Itamar leads the development of RHEV, he knows.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mix different hosts with different RAM sizes and CPU counts, as long as the cluster CPU is at the same baseline. The RHEV scheduler is clever enough to distribute VMs across different hosts according to their resources.